# API to Populate MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS

Tags: oracle, oracle-ebs

What are the standard APIs to populate the tables below in Oracle EBS R12?

```
Table name
-----------------------
MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES
MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS
MTL_CROSS_REFERENCES
MTL_CUSTOMER_ITEM_XREFS
```

Provide any link or pointers if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These seeded tables are not being populated via an API. You need to populate their interfaces tables then run the Concurrent Program "Import Items".
If there will be records that has any errors, it will be inserted into `MTL_INTERFACE_ERRORS`.
See the sample of the required columns and values to be populated [here](https://imdjkoch.wordpress.com/tag/mtl_system_items_interface/).

```
BASE TABLE              INTERFACE_TABLE                 ERROR_TABLE             CONCURRENT_REQUESTS / PROCESSES
----------------        ------------------------------  ---------------------   --------------------------------
MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS        MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_INTERFACE      MTL_INTERFACE_ERRORS    Import Items
MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES     MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES_INTERFACE   MTL_INTERFACE_ERRORS    Import Items    
MTL_CROSS_REFERENCES    MTL_CROSS_REFERENCES_INTERFACE  MTL_INTERFACE_ERRORS    
MTL_CUSTOMER_ITEM_XREFS MTL_CI_XREFS_INTERFACE          MTL_INTERFACE_ERRORS    Customer Item Interface -> Customer Item Cross-Reference Interface
```

More links that may help:

1. [Oracle Manufacturing APIs and Open Interfaces Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A88418_02/acrobat/115mfgoim.pdf) (this is
   for 11i but it would most probably still work for R12).
2. [Item import (Item conversion)](http://www.shareoracleapps.com/2010/01/item-import-item-conversion.html)
3. [Item category assignment open interface](http://oracletechnofunctional.webs.com/apps/blog/show/32164988-item-category-assignment-open-interface)
4. [EBS Interfaces](http://ebshelp.blogspot.com/2011/12/ebs-interfaces.html)
5. [Inventory ( INV ) Open Interfaces](http://www.oracleappsquery.com/?q=oracle-apps-r12-Inventory-INV-Open-Interfaces)